# How does Oracle prevent memory from being paged out from the SGA?

Tags: oracle, memory, operating-system

In Oracle RDBMS there is a parameter called `lock_sga` that can prevent the SGA space from being paged out from memory.

How can this be possible? I thought memory that is paged out is done so at the discretion of the OS and transparent to other processes? Why are applications allowed control over this?

**Part 2:**
Is it possible that I could write a program that could allocate all the machine's memory, and then lock that allocation in place to prevent the OS from paging it out? What would happen?

Comment: When requesting memory from the OS applications can ask for the memory to be locked, this is obviously an OS specific call. eg  `VirtualLock` on MS-Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx  Read __Remarks__ to answer your __Part 2__

Comment: It is platform specific, but also somewhat historical.  It is rare nowadays to ever need to specify lock_sga on an Oracle database install.  What is typically of more importance is using a large/huge pages if appropriate on your particular OS.

Answer (score 0):

if u system based on linux 64
use huge pages for sga like discribe:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/configuring-huge-pages-for-oracle-on-linux-64